# How do I send a string to a Repl.it Node.js Server from C# application

Tags: c#, node.js

I've been trying to send a string (from a C# application) to a Node.js Server on [Repl.it](https://repl.it)

I would put my C# code up but one problem is that I've changed it so many times to fit different methods that it has a few too many errors for me to want to try and debug.

Is there another website that does the same thing as Repl.it that I can use?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with Node.js server? Have you configured it correctly (for example, CORS)?

Comment: To quick check - you can send request to your server from browser console with JS: `fetch('https://your.server/with/endpoint/').then(console.log)`

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your c# and node.js code

Comment: @MikeKaskun I tried to put it into the Console that Repl.it Provided but that didn't work I'm not to sure if that was the right Console that you meant but I got this error for reference "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined:"

Comment: @mihai I would put My C# code it but I currently have no Method to Send it but my Node Js code im Currently Working With can be found at this Link link Which Should I think Log when Something Connects to it that's all I've got so far to the both of you Just note that This is my first Time Working with Node.js